# Do amputated feynman diagrams contribute to scattering amplitude more than once?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Suppose I want to compute the scattering amplitude for some interaction and I want to include contributions up to order $k$ in the perturbative series. Suppose that $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m<n$. Suppose I amputate a Feynman diagram at order $n$, and after amputation it equals a diagram at order $m$.

Is it correct to (a) include the diagram twice, (i.e. both the diagram at order $m$ and the amputated diagram at order $n$) or (b) should the amputated diagram be discarded altogether as it's included already at order $m$?

It suffices to answer (a) or (b). I need no further justification, just to know the answer.

EDIT: An example included from $\phi^4$ theory. The example is taken from Peskin page 113.

[image]

Comment: I am having a hard time to imagine a situation where "[...] I amputate a Feynman diagram at order $n$, and after amputation it equals a diagram at order $m$. ". How can an amputated diagram be equal to a non-amputated diagram? Can you include an example of a diagram where this happens?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform loving your username. I've added a figure with an example. The example is from $\phi^4$ scalar theory (taken from Peskin page 113). In this case $m = 1$ and $n = 2$

Comment: [thanks :-)] I see. I had something else in mind when thinking about amputation (I thought you meant just to remove the propagators, not to strip off the legs). Are you using these diagrams to compute $S$ matrix elements or correlation functions? In other words, what do the external legs stand for? are they propagators or just a factor of $1$?

Comment: I'm not sure if they are propagators or just 1. I think they are 1 in momentum space, but $e^{-ipx}$ in position space. I want to compute $\langle \vec{p}_1\cdots \vec{p}_k| iT |\vec{k}_A \vec{k}_B \rangle$. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that means that you are calculating a scattering amplitude (aka, an $S$ matrix element). In that case, your first diagram does not contribute, because only amputated diagrams contribute to scattering amplitudes. In other words, you need only consider the "X" diagram, not the one in the l.h.s.

Comment: That much is clear, but is the answer to the question above (a) or (b)? I.e. is the diagram X considered twice (one contribution from order m and one from order n), or just from order m?

Comment: Only once. You *always* consider a diagram only once.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform sometimes even less than once, hehe (I'm talking about the symmetry factors).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/463536/2451